# Loading data for multiple tabs

Tags: android, tabs, loading

I have FragmentActivity with ViewPager that holds 3 tabs of Fragments. Each of the fragments has its own URL where it needs to send request and fetch data in JSON format. This works well as long user does not tap on any of the tabs till loaders finished their job. However if the user tap on 2nd or 3rd tab while JSON loading in progress  these may not load properly.

Is there anything I can do to keep mu current parallel loading approach (each fragment fetching data for it self), but ensuring all data are loaded properly instead of moving loaders to FragmentActivity and doing loading serially from Activity and pushing data to Fragments(with square Otto)?

Comment: I wish that people when they down vote leave comment with reason and not cowardly stay annonyous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest you have a look at [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

and the method [setOffscreenPageLimit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29)

Comment: It is not final solution but  yes limiting to 1 does improve ViewPager loaders issue.